# Docker & Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker with symfony 3.4
All is working fine (sql8, phpmyadmin) but php don't work ...

When i go to localhost:9000 (phpmyadmin in my docker) that's work but when i go to localhost:8000 (symfony) that's don't work ...

When i run `php binconsole server:run` all is working fine (changing parameters.yml file of course)

I don't understand because when i run docker i have the message

> [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000

But the page don't work ...

Here my docker-compose :

```
version: "3"

services:
apache:
  build: ./docker/apache/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  depends_on:
    - php
php:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    - db
db:
  image: mysql:8.0.0
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
  restart: always
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=dashboard
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  environment:
    - PMA_HOST=db
    - PMA_PORT=3306
  ports:
    - "9000:80"
  links:
    - db
```

My dockerfile php:

```
FROM php:7.3-rc-zts-alpine

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install

COPY . .

CMD php bin/console server:run
```

If you want more information i put all in a git (run `make docker-all`) : https://github.com/Luisrosario2604/Symfony-Docker

Links : phpmyadmin in localhost:9000 (user: root, passwd: toor)

Php : Should be localhost 8000

(I am new with docker so it's possible i did an idiot mistake)

Thx for all that will take time for me :)

Comment: You cannot access using port 80?

Comment: Do you mean that i have to try with port 80 for php ? like port "80:8000"

Comment: i can access to port 80 (that goes to apache2 debian default page)

Comment: Is it possible to configure to listen for `http://0.0.0.0:80/` instead?

Comment: Sure i will try it !

Comment: Hoo woaw thx you so mutch @Hitobat The answer : listen symfony to 0.0.0.0:8000
For this just run : php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000

Thx you so mutch i have this problem since 2 days !